# S3: custom headers return a 403

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've got an app that uploads documents to an S3 bucket. No problems there, but when I specify some custom headers in the request like so:

```
req.setHeader('x-amz-meta-purpose', 'purpose');
```

And write matching CORS rules for the bucket:

```
<CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>http://www.example.com</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
   <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSec>
   <ExposeHeader>x-amz-meta-purpose</ExposeHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

I get a 403 response. What am I forgetting? My code works fine without the custom header added.

**Update**

I get this response:

```
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
```

How do I change my signature to include the custom header? It's currently made like this:

```
String stringToSign = 'PUT\n\n' + contentType + '\n' + now + '\n' + '/' + bucketname + '/' + lead.Id + '/' + fileName;
String encodedStringToSign = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(stringToSign, 'UTF-8');
Blob mac = Crypto.generateMac('HMACSHA1', Blob.valueOf(stringToSign), Blob.valueOf(secret));
String signed = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac);
```

Any ideas or documentation on how to add headers to that?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve using that Custom header?

Comment: Have you examined the response body of the 403 for an explanation?  Many S3 errors have useful information in the body XML.  The most likely explanation is that the additional headers are not being properly or fully taken into account when calculating the signature.

Comment: You're right, @Michael-sqlbot. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Signature V2, so you need to include the "Canonicalized Amz Headers"...

```
String stringToSign = 'PUT\n\n' + 
                      contentType + '\n' + 
                      now + '\n' + 
>>>>>> here >>>>>>    CanonicalizedAmzHeaders +
                      '/' + bucketname + '/' + lead.Id + '/' + fileName;
```

Note there is no additional '\n' needed after this new value, but it the `CanonicalizedAmzHeaders` string, itself, ends with a '\n'.

Canonicalized Amz headers is built by iterating through each header beginning with `x-amz-`, with the header names converted to lowercase and then sorted lexically, building a string that looks like this (pseudocode):

```
lowercase(header1) + ':' + trim(value1) + '\n' +
lowercase(header2) + ':' + trim(value2) + '\n' +
...
```

So, in your request, it would the last three lines would look like this:

```
[date]\n
x-amz-meta-purpose:purpose\n
/bucketname/key
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#ConstructingTheCanonicalizedResourceElement

Comment: Thank-you so much.